# Understanding the parallelizing of iterative processes in mpi4py

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi4py

Let us assume that there are two np.arrays with `SIZE_X` size: `Hx` and `Ex`. Next, suppose that there are two procedures, `H_update()` and `E_update()`, that sequentially update the values of these two arrays in iterative way.

```
def H_update(Hx, Ex):
    for i in range(1, SIZE_X - 1):
        Hx[i] += Ex[i] - Ex[i-1]

def E_update(Hx, Ex):
    for i in range(1, SIZE_X - 1):
        Ex[i] +=  Hx[i+1] - Hx[i]
```

Next, we will model a `field()` in which we will simply iteratively recalculate the values of H and E.

```
def field(frames):
    Res = []
    for n in range(0, frames):
        H_update(Hx, Ex)
        E_update(Hx, Ex)
        Ex[SIZE_X // 2] += 1
        Res.append(np.copy(Ex))
    return Res
```

**Parallelization proposal**

Let's divide all calculations between ranks, so each process can handle part of H and E arrays from  `start_x` to `end_x` points.

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

global frames

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

def H_update_par(Hx, Ex, start_x, end_x):
    for i in range(1 + start_x, end_x):
        Hx[i] += Ex[i] - Ex[i-1]

def E_update_par(Hx, Ex, start_x, end_x):
    for i in range(1 + start_x, end_x):
        Ex[i] +=  Hx[i+1] - Hx[i]

def construct_field(frames):
    local_size_x = int(SIZE_X / size)
    start_x = rank * local_size_x
    end_x = (rank + 1) * local_size_x if rank < size - 1 else SIZE_X - 1
    Res = []
    for n in range(frames):
        if n % size == rank:
            H_update_par(Hx, Ex, start_x, end_x)
            E_update_par(Hx, Ex, start_x, end_x)
            if rank == 0:
                Ex[SIZE_X // 2] += 1
            Res.append(np.copy(Ex))
        comm.barrier()
        Hx = comm.bcast(Hx, root=0)
        Ex = comm.bcast(Ex, root=0)
    return Res

if __name__== "__main__":
    loc = construct_field(100, 0)
    Ex = comm.gather(loc, root=0)
    if rank == 0:
        Ex = sum(Ex, [])
        print(Ex)
```

**Problem**

The code version above has a problem that does not allow calculations to be performed correctly. For example, in `H_update()` we would like to update the values of `Hx[1]` and `Hx[2]`, however, if `SIZE_X = 4`  and the number of processes `size = 2` the first process will update the `Hx[1]` value and transfer it to `E_update()` function, but `Hx[2]` value still not updated, so calculations will be failed.

**The question** is, how do I update the values of H[i] and H[i+1] for correct calculations in parallel if H[i] is considered one process and H[i+1] is considered another process?